# Yamaha digital piano pedal connector

Tags: piano, digital-piano, keyboard-pedals

I know nothing about piano but recently got one (Yamaha PF1500). It came with a stand with two pedal. According to the owner's manual, the sustain and soft pedals are connected to the left and right ports respectively.

[image]

But the cables are concealed inside the stand. When they come out, I have no way to tell which one is which. All I see that one jack is grey (left one) and the other is black in color.

[image]

Could anyone help me to figure out which one is which? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Plug them both in, either way round.   Play the piano.  Press the right-hand pedal.  If you get sustain rather than reduced volume, you got it right.  Otherwise swap the plugs.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 50:50 on this one! Not a lot of choices really, and hardly worth posting the question, tbh.

Plug one (say black) into the sustain port. Press down the right pedal. If that allows the note to continue sounding when your finger releases the key, that's the sustain pedal jack. If not, then it must be the other jack.

Generally speaking, the sustain is located on the right of the pair. So that's the one it should be. If one jack doesn't do the job it should be the other.

There is, to me little use for the other (soft) pedal. Turn down the volume instead. That would be more use as a sostenuto but it's not avaiable on that keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Hold one connector, and gently tug at the other end. That will tell you which cable is which.